# How can we catch save button action in lightning:listView?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, inline, lightninglistview

I am working to create an aura:component that contains lightning:listView.
I succeeded in creating a lightning:listView.
But I don't know how to catch the save button action of inline edit like lightning:dataTable.
Please let me know if you know anything about saving inline edits.
Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to catch it?

Comment: Hi @KrisGoncalves. I want to rewrite the save process to make an API callout.I perform various calculations at the connection destination of the API. And I want to decide whether or not to save according to the API response. This is not suitable for triggers. So I'm looking for a way to catch the save. Thank you.